# window.navigator or just navigator?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

What object I should use to determine browser's info?

```
alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

or

```
alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

Is there any recomendations about cross-browser compatibility of a decision?

Comment: Run `navigator === window.navigator` and you will see that it is the same object. That said, using `window` is more explicit and clearly shows your intention to use the global object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Either, it doesn't really matter.  `navigator` is a property of the `window` object, but all properties of the `window` object are accessible as global variables.

```
navigator === window.navigator;
//-> true
```

As a personal preference, I always write `window.propertyName` for explicit properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this ....

```
 alert("You're using " + navigator.appName);
```

for reference  pls go through  this link [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator)